The norm of a linear functional is the same as the sum of the norm of its components with respect to the characteristic functions
Here, we use $l^\infty$ to denote the set of bounded sequences in $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that $L: l^\infty\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a bounded linear functional. Let $U_j, j = 1,2,\cdots, J$ be a partition of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\varphi_j$ be the characteristic function on $U_j$ for each $j$. Define $\varphi_jL: l^\infty\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ by
$$
u\mapsto L(\varphi_ju).
$$
I was asked to prove that
$$
||L|| = \sum_{j = 1}^J||\varphi_jL||.
$$
It's easy to observe that $||L||\leq \sum_{j = 1}^J||\varphi_jL||$, since $L = \sum_{j = 1}^J \varphi_jL$. I find it hard to prove the other direction. My attempt is as follows:
Let $N_j = ||\varphi_j L||$ for each $j$. Take $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $u_j\in l^\infty$, $||u_j|| = 1$ such that $|L(\varphi_ju_j)| > N_j - \epsilon$. As long as we can show that
$$
||L||\geq \left| L \left(\frac{u_1 + \cdots u_J}{J}\right)\right|\geq \sum_{j = 1}^J \left|L \left(\frac{u_j}{J}\right)\right|\geq \sum_{j = 1}^J|L(\varphi_ju_j)|
$$
we are done. But I think some inequality above is wrong...
Could someone help point out the intuition about why $||L|| = \sum_{j = 1}^J||\varphi_jL||$? The supremum of each $\frac{|L(\varphi_ju)|}{||u||}$ might be achieved by different $u$, so I don't see why it's an equality.
Thanks!

Note that, in your notation, $\varphi_j L(u_j) = \varphi_j L (\varphi_j u_j)$ (as $\varphi_j^2 = \varphi_j$), so you can WLOG assume that $u_j$ is zero outside $U_j$ (if not just consider $\tilde{u}_j = \varphi_j u_j$). Further, by possibly considering $\alpha u_j$ instead of $u_j$ for some suitable complex unit $\alpha$, you can suppose that $\varphi_j L(u_j) = | \varphi_j L (u_j) | > N_j - \frac{\epsilon}{J}$.
But then $\| u_1 + \dots + u_J \| \leq 1$ and for $i \neq j$ we have $\varphi_i u_j = 0$. You can then proceed like you suggested:
$$||L||\geq |L(u_1 + \cdots + u_J)| = \left| \sum_{j=1}^J \varphi_jL(u_j) \right| \geq \sum_{j=1}^J N_j - \epsilon.$$

Wait I think the last inequality might not hold? It should be a $\leq$ sign (I made a mistake in my original post as well...)

Edited to answey your comment. It is a nice commonly used trick to multiply a given $x$ by a complex unit $\alpha$ in order to get rid of absoulte value of the value of some functional.
